# Confused as to how to compute this derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

The question asks us to compute the derivative of the following:

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\left(x+10\right)^{10}}{\left(2x-4\right)^{10}}$

Now, by using the natural log and various rules related to that, I've arrived to:

$f\left(x\right)=10ln\left(x+1\right)-10ln\left(2x-4\right)$

What confuses me is the next step in my professor's notes. He taught this concept to us very quickly so I can't follow what he's doing. He ends up doing the below:

$\frac{1}{f\left(x\right)}\cdot f\:'\left(x\right)=\frac{10}{x+1}\left(1\right)-\frac{10}{2x-4}\left(2\right)$

Which cancels various things out. I don't know why he's multipled the LHS by $\frac{1}{f\left(x\right)}$ or the other terms by (1) and (2). Is he using other log rules for derivatives?

Comment: The LHS of equation 1 is not $f(x)$, but $\ln f(x)$.  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Ah, I see - so is he applying ln to both sides again?

Comment: Not "again".  Just once in the first equation.  The second equation is arrived at by taking the derivative of each side of the first equation, and applying the chain rule.  See Michael's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that 
$$
f(x)=\frac{(x+10)^{10}}{(2x-4)^{10}}.
$$

Then, applying the logarithm to both sides gives 
$$
\ln f(x)=10\ln(x+10)-10\ln(2x-4).
$$

Taking the derivative of both sides gives (remembering the chain rule to give the factor of $2$ in the right-most term).  The chain rule also gives the $f'(x)$ on the LHS.
$$
\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)=10\cdot \frac{1}{x+10}-10\cdot \frac{1}{2x-4}\cdot 2
$$

Then, multiplying by $f(x)$ on both sides gives
$$
f'(x)=\frac{10f(x)}{x+10}-\frac{20f(x)}{2x-4}.
$$

Comment: The chain rule. I can't believe I didn't spot that. Thank you so much, this finally makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = ln(g(x))$ where $g(x) = {(x+10)^{10}\over(2x-4)^{10}}$

By the chain rule, $f'(x) = {g'(x)\over g(x)}$

Since $f'(x) = {10\over x+1} + 2{10\over2x-4}$ we get

$$
g'(x) = g(x) \left({10\over x+1} + 2{10\over2x-4} \right)
$$